# Como obter n dia útil do mês?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

Estou criando um modelo de dados para Machine Learning para obter uma previsão de quantidade de transações por ano/mes/dia/hora.

Porém eu estou precisando mapear o 5º e 10º dia útil do mês para que meu algoritmo preveja que são dias de grande movimento e assim os números ficarem mais próximos de valores reais.

Dei uma pesquisada já em algumas bibliotecas e achei uma de nome Workalendar, onde eu passo uma data e qual o dia útil que preciso e ele me retorna a data, abaixo segue um exemplo de utilização.

```
from workalendar.america import Brazil
cal = Brazil()
print(cal.add_working_days(date(2019, 12, 1), 5))
...
2019-12-06
```

O problema é que estou tendo dificuldade em passar para a minhas variáveis 0 ou 1 para validar que o dia útil é de fato o que eu preciso. Tentei fazer um laço de repetição e varrer o dataframe todo passando a data e o dia útil, entretanto não consegui achar uma forma de informar que o valor retornado é valido ou não. :(

Alguém já teve esse problema conseguiu resolver esse problema com alguma formula matemática ou coisa parecida?

*Obs.: Dei um olhada no código da biblioteca para ver se achava algo, mas não entendi bem como eles calculam o n dia útil.*

Comment: Apenas lembrando que para contar apenas os dias úteis você terá que considerar os feriados, que podem ser nacionais, estaduais ou municipais.

Comment: Quanto aos feriados, estou mapeando eles manualmente e fazendo um merge para selecionar se uma data é dia útil ou não. Por exemplo, se eu conseguisse o 5º dia útil porém ele fosse um feriado estadual o dia útil seria o próximo.

Comment: Coloque o que você tentou

Comment: Eu estava fazendo uma comparação "burra", rsrs. Consegui resolver o meu problema usando a lib workalendar! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui fazer, mesmo que parecendo uma gambiarra de certo! kkk

```
for i in range(len(dados)):
if(dados['data'][i] == pd.Timestamp(cal.add_working_days(date(anos[i], meses[i], 1), 5))):
    dados['dia5'][i] = 1
if(dados['data'][i] == pd.Timestamp(cal.add_working_days(date(anos[i], meses[i], 1), 10))):
    dados['dia10'][i] = 1
```

Basicamente eu solicitei uma comparação de todos os dados do DataFrame para retornar uma data válida com a que eu esperava. Porém precisei converter o retorno da função de **datetime** para **pandas.Timestamp**.

Eu estava fazendo ao contrário e não estava dando muito certo por causa da hora embutida no timestamp, na hora de converter os dois não ficam *iguais* de fato.

Se alguém tiver alguma solução mais esperta,  por favor informe no post.